# Set Combobox Item from C# using Value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have combobox in my XAML window,I have one datatable which contains two columns **ID,Name**. I bind that datable in to combobox items using below code.

```
cBox.SelectedValuePath="ID";
cBox.DisplayMemberPath="Name";
cBox.ItemsSource = dtable.DefaultView;
```

What I want is, I want to select particular item from c# using **ID (not Name)**, then it will select 1st element of the combobox like below

```
cBox.SelectedIndex = 0/1/2/3/...;
```

If I use below code, it will select any item in the combobox but I want to select combobox item **using ID**

```
 cBox.Text = dtable.Rows[1][1].ToString();
```

Comment: did you try `cBox.SelectedValue = dtable.Rows[1]["ID"];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the **selectedValue** property..

try the below

```
cBox.SelectedValue = dtable.Rows[1][0].ToString();
```

you can download the working sample from here..

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2dGZOMjc0SlRJVWc

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already checked that but it is not working(not selecting the value)

Comment: it is working.. I have tried then only replying you..!

Comment: check the link posted in answer

Comment: so you found where you made mistake?? let us know where you made mistake.. so that other can also find their fault before going  to be crazy for that mistake..

Comment: It is working fine, the problem with mismatch of datatable column in c# and this line cBox.SelectedValuePath="ID";